# Dinamically rescale GameObject Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale

I need to rescale a `GameObject` in Unity3D, basing on a speed value. I am trying to do it through the `transform.localScale`, and computing a size ratio basing on the highest speed and dimension values; however, it does not work as it should.

The problem I have is that with the starting size of `{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}`, and with `speedValues = {0.8, 0.5, 0.2}`, I have that `_sizeRatio = 0.625` and the object is not kept to its original scale but is rescaled. I do not know how to solve this issue.

Here is a sample of the code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Input;
using System.Linq;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject objectToResize;    
    [SerializeField] private float[] speedValues;

    private int _speedIndex;

    
    private float _sizeRatio;
    private Vector3 _originalSize;
    
    private void Start(){
        _speedIndex = 0;
        _originalSize = objectToResize.transform.localScale;
        _sizeRatio = _originalSize.x / GetMaxValue(v);
        ScaleObject();
    }
    
    private void Update(){
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W){
            _speedIndex++
            if(_speedIndex == speedValues.Length){
                _speedIndex = 0:
            }
            ScaleObject();
        }
    }
    
    private void ScaleObject(){
        var newScale = new Vector3(_originalSize.x * _sizeRatio * speedValues[_speedIndex],
            _originalSize.y * _sizeRatio * speedValues[_speedIndex],
            _originalSize.z * _sizeRatio * speedValues[_experimentManager.SpeedIndex]);

        objectToResize.transform.localScale = newScale;
    }
    
    private float GetMaxValue(float[] v) => v.Max();
    
}
```

Comment: Instead of the current `scale.y` etc have you tried to rather use the `_originalSize`? Since your `_sizeRatio` is based on that one it seems to make more sense

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should use the `_originalSize`. However, it makes no difference: it does not work anyway